# Retorna o mês anterior de uma data informada na Qt

Tags: c++, datetime, qt, qtgui

Como que faço para retorna o mês anterior da data informada na Qt, tem alguma função no `QDate` que faz isso? Achei apenas a que adiciona `addMonths`. Exemplo: mês 04 informado retorna mês 03.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, o método [`month()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#month) faz isto.

```
QDate data(2015, 4, 6);
int mes = data.month();
```

De acordo com o comentário abaixo o que é desejado é subtrair meses, então usa o próprio [`addMonths()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#addMonths), basta usar um valor negativo.

```
QDate data(2015, 4, 6);
int mesAnterior = data.addMonths(-1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Qt/Date.cpp).

Comment: bigown é agora. Como faço para retorna o mês anterior(Que já passou)? Exemplo data.month() retorna mês 04, agora gostaria que ele retornasse 03.

Comment: Não estava claro na pergunta que era o mês anterior que você desejava.

Comment: Obrigado bigown. Funcionou agora. `data.addMonths(-1).toString("dd/MM/yyyy");`